# How to set Credentials for Publisher for Google PubSub

Tags: google-cloud-pubsub

I am using the newer version of PubSub - [Publisher API](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-java/blob/master/google-cloud-examples/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/examples/pubsub/snippets/CreateTopicAndPublishMessages.java#L51)

I have a P12 file and am building the credential like this:

```
GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
            .setTransport(transport)
            .setJsonFactory(JSON_FACTORY)
            .setServiceAccountId(serviceAccount)
            .setServiceAccountScopes(Arrays.asList("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/pubsub")) 
            .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(new File(keyFile))
            .build();
```

How do I set the credentials on the Publisher?
Also, is there a way to get the static scope string `"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/pubsub"`

Comment: It's simpler to use Google Application Credentials, as demonstrated in this sample: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-java/blob/master/google-cloud-examples/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/examples/pubsub/snippets/TopicAdminClientSnippets.java.  Is that option not available to you?  Must you use a P12?

Answer (score 2):

I found the question answered [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-java/issues/1751) in case anyone runs into this:

Basically,

```
Publisher
  .defaultBuilder(topic)
  .setChannelProvider(TopicAdminSettings
  .defaultChannelProviderBuilder()
  .setCredentialsProvider(FixedCredentialsProvider.create(yourCredentialsHere))
  .build())
.build();
```

Comment: Only thing is this needs json version of the key instead of P12